# How did 'unless' evolve to mean 'if not'?

Tags: etymology

> [[Etymonline:]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=unless&searchmode=none) mid-15c., earlier *onlesse*, from *on lesse* (than) "`on a less condition (than)`; see [less](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=less&allowed_in_frame=0). The first syllable originally [on](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=on&allowed_in_frame=0), but the ***negative*** connotation and the lack of stress changed it to *un-*. ...

[*OED* (3rd edn, 2017)](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/215075?redirectedFrom=unless#eid):

> [[†](http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-symbols-and-other-conventions)A.] 2. Forming a conjunctional phrase introducing a case in which an exception to a preceding (or following) statement will or may exist: except if, **if..not**.

1. How did `on a less condition (than)` shift to *onlesse*, and then **if not**?

2. What and where is the '***negative***  connotation'?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I did mean to ask about 'etymology' though, not meaning. I already know that **unless = if not**. But how does *onlesse* => **if not**?

Comment: Dude, no need to keep stating that you 'recognise the Etymological Fallacy', you either show by your question that you do, or you don't, stating it doesn't make it so. Also, like many questions lately, there is no real answer to 'how' or 'why', there's only description 'that it has done so'. The 'why' is that things change, usually from one thing to a similar one. Maybe you're looking for a missing link because the gap is too large for you? Maybe you're looking for more details to the etymology? And asking 'why' is a great start,  but all there is is 'that' here.

Comment: @Mitch In the past, some questions have been closed because the closers erred in thinking that the poster didn't 'recognise the Etymological Fallacy'. Does this help? Yes, to both of your questions: `Maybe you're looking for a missing link because the gap is too large for you? Maybe you're looking for more details to the etymology?`.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit And questions *will continue* to be closed when the poster fails to recognize the Etymological Fallacy, as this one does. As Mitch said, simply stating that *you've heard there's such a thing* does not protect you from such closure; you have to *demonstrate* through your *actions*, not your *words*, that you're *avoiding it*. An analogy: you're standing in the street, repeatedly stabbing a now-lifeless corpse with a knife. A dozen more lie behind you. A cop walks up, and you say "Now officer, before you start, *I know there's a law against murder*, but...".

Comment: 1. The OED has the first definition 'on a less condition' with citations only in the 1400's (and questionably the same syntax as unless 'on less than'). The second definition is 'if not' with citations from 1500. The ideas are so similar that I don't see much to add than to say it's easy for things to slip (see multiple meanings of 'since'). 2.The second condition is 'less' 3. 'less' is in the negative/'not' direction, like 'but'.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd say it means "provided" - A = B _provided_ C hasn't happened. I can't see it meaning "if not". OED must have got it's knickers in a twist.

Comment: @DanBron Are you saying that you closed the question because you disagree with my interest in etymology? So your problem was not one of research? But this is a concern entirely separate from the close reason, which was stated as 'sufficient research'. I always try to avoid the Etymological Fallacy.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit I didn't close your question. Though I think your interest lies not so much in etymology but using etymology (inappropriately) to try to force words to make sense. I am frustrated by your resistance to acknowledging that you are falling prey to this fallacy, but that doesn't influence my decision to close or not close your questions. In general, I leave them alone.

Comment: @DanBron Thank you. In answer to `I didn't close your question`, from the question log, I see: `  Post Closed as "off-topic" by Mari-Lou A, Dan Bron,...`. So to clarify, was this a technical error?  I apologise for any confusion.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit Huh, no, if it's in the log, then I must have done so. Which is weird because I typically leave your questions alone. It may have been in this case that it was in the review queue, where I had seen others VtC, which may have influenced my decision.  (My process for voting in the review queue differs from my on-the-stop decisions to vote on questions which appear on the front page.) But I don't know, I certainly don't remember closing your Q.

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3815693/why-does-unless-mean-if-not/3815703

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The etymology of *unless*, much like the similar one of *lest*, does in fact seem rather puzzling, but the archaic first meaning I found in the [OED's 2nd ed. (1989)](http://www.oed.com/oed2/00268144) [3rd ed. (2017) differs] confirmed the theory I came up with right after learning that it derives from *on less than*:

> On a less or lower condition, requirement, footing, etc., *than* (what is specified). With preceding negative, expressed or implied.

So it started with a wording that still makes sense today:

> I won't go to the cinema and watch this stupid film with the children *on less than [that]* you accompany us!

The actual first recorded use in the OED is from a passage in Maundeville (c. 1400) about the antipodes (see the first sentence under [Definition 1](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/215075?redirectedFrom=unless#eid)):

> "But þat may not be vpon less þan wee mowe falle toward heuene."

In modernised English:  "But that may not be on less than we may fall toward the sky."
Clearly making sense of *upon less* is the least of our difficulties understanding this sentence today.

Apparently, as often happens with emphatic ways of expressing something, the idiom *on less than* became so popular and overused that its meaning detached from the individual words, faded and generalised. Uses of *on less than* in the generalised sense of *if not* even without it [= the phrase *on less than*] following a negated statement were recorded just a few decades after Maundeville.

Once *on less than* had become a full synonym of *if not* or *except*, it was natural to leave out the word *than*, making the etymology slightly obscure even in the original use case and even more so when not following a negation. The path was paved for wondering if the first word was *on* or *un-* as they can sound pretty much the same. (I would also expect that even at this early stage people often dropped the word *on* altogether, as they still often do with *[un]less*.)

I think what is meant by the negative connotation of *unless* that facilitated change of *on* to *un-* is that *unless* is now understood as a synonym of *if **not***. Due to some fuzzy thinking this could in fact have made it appear logical that somewhere there should be a negation in *unless*. But I personally think a much more important factor will have been that *on* and *less* were merged into a single word *onless*, and that *un-* is vastly more common as a prefix than *on-*. I think it's normal and quite common for a rare prefix to be replaced by a common one that has essentially the same pronunciation, regardless of any differences in meaning.

Comment: +1. Thanks. 1. Would you please clarify `in the original use case` (in your penultimate para)? Does this contain a typo?

Comment: @LePressentiment: I am not proud of my choice of words "original use case". *It* refers to "on less". The important point behind both passages was that originally, "on less" could always be understood literally as e.g. in "not ... based on less than ..." or "not ... on less provocation than ...".

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see how the [etymological fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy) (the mistaken belief that the "true" or "proper" meaning of a word is its oldest or original meaning) relates to current usage of ***unless***.

OED's "etymology" for the word says...

> ***less*** ... *with the prepositions **of, in, upon,** and **on** ; the last of these by want of stress<sup>1</sup> has been assimilated in form to the prefix **un-***

Semantically, the specific preposition is fairly irrelevant. Casual/dialectal speakers commonly discard it completely (I have no opinion on whether the apostrophe *should* be present)...

> [*"I won't go **'less** you do, Josh," said Lester.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20less%20you%20do%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)
> [*"You don't have to go **less** you want to."*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22You%20don%27t%20have%20to%20go%20less%20you%20want%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

The *syntax* of the usage has obviously changed (apart from "prefixing" with **of, in, upon,** etc., it used to be possible to follow it with ***that, than***, etc., for example). But personally I can't see that the *meaning* has really changed much.

The only (*very* slight) semantic shift I can see is that originally the condition was effectively a *minimum* (the ***least*** thing that's required), but nowadays it's normally used without the speaker being consciously aware of that original nuance (now it's usually the ***only*** thing that will do).

---

<sup>1</sup> Odd/dated phrasing by OED. They mean *because there's no [spoken] stress [on the syllable]*.

Comment: +1. Thanks. Would you please clarify whether your answer discussed the claimed ''negative connotation' (ie question 2 in my OP)?