# What is 'less' about 'unless'?

Tags: meaning, etymology, ambiguity

> [[Etymonline:]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=unless&searchmode=none) unless (conj.) [:]
>   mid-15c., earlier *onlesse*, from *on lesse* (than) "on a ***less*** **condition**" (than); see [less](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=less&allowed_in_frame=0).
>   The first syllable originally [on](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=on&allowed_in_frame=0), but the negative connotation and the lack of stress changed it to *un-*. Except could once be used as a synonym for unless, but the words have now drawn entirely apart" [Century Dictionary].
>
> [[Source:]](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/244691/50720) The only (*very* slight) semantic shift I can see is that originally the **condition** was effectively a *minimum* (the LEAST thing that's required), but nowadays it's normally used without the speaker being consciously aware of that original nuance
>   (now it's usually the ONLY thing that will do).

Despite the above, I still don't understand what is ***less*** in 'unless'. What does **condition** mean above?    Does it refer to the clause before 'unless', 'unless' itself, or the clause after 'unless'?

Footnote: I changed the formatting of the original quote for clarity, but not the text.
I don't quote the brusquer [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/215075?redirectedFrom=unless#eid), which doesn't discuss such a **condition**.

Comment: 'Only if a certain condition is met / exceeded.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think it's the other way around, isn't it? It means if this condition *isn't* met (i.e.you have *less* than this condition), then xyz. So "Unless I pass my exam, I won't be able to go on holiday" means "on less than my passing my exams, I won't be able to go on holiday". That's how I read it, anyhow ...but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 2):

You would do well to read OED more carefully. [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio101murruoft#page/256/mode/2up)'s definition for the earliest meaning is

> †1. *prep.phr.*  On a less or lower condition, requirement, footing, etc., *than* what is specified.
>   **With preceding negative, express or implied.** [my emphasis]

That is, the sense is "**not** on a less compelling condition than" what follows, NOT "On a less compelling condition than" what follows.

In modern terminology, *on less* (like modern *unless*) is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item): it only occurs in a negative context.

Here's the first quotation *OED 1* gives, in modern spelling.

> *c* **1400** [...] But that may not be upon less than we may fall toward heaven.

That is, "That cannot happen on any less condition than our being able to fall upwards."

> **1475** [...] His land, which many people .. fear to take .., unless than they might be made very sure of payment.

That is, people will **not** take the land on any less condition than that of being assured that they will be paid. Here *fear* supplies the necessary negative context.

Comment: Is modern "unless" a negative polarity item? It doesn't seem to be to me: I can say things like "I will do it tomorrow, unless I forget".