# How to understand 'unless' = 'on a less or lower condition', in: 'Don't X, unless Y'?

Tags: etymology, unless

[*OED* (3rd edn, 2017)](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/215075?redirectedFrom=unless#eid):

> [[†](http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-symbols-and-other-conventions)A.] 1. Forming a conjunctional phrase introducing a case in which an exception to a preceding negative statement (expressed or implied) will or may exist: (not) on a less or lower condition, requirement, etc., *than* (what is specified). *[Obs[olete].](https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-symbols-and-other-conventions/)*

Let's contemplate:

> 2. Exercise, **unless** you spurn healthfulness.

that ought to mean:

> 3. Exercise, **if** you  spurn **not** healthfulness.

Here's the snag. If I substitute 1  into 2,  then 2 becomes:

> 4. Exercise, **(not) on a less or lower condition, requirement *than*** you spurn healthfulness.

But how does 4 signify the same as 3?

Comment: Notice how your definition says ***obsolete***?  You cannot explain how 2, a current phrase, means what you propose in 4 because in 2 *unless* does not take on the obsolete definition you cite in 1.

Comment: The definition uses the word "than". This does not mean that the word being defined is found in combination with the word "than".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [StoneyB's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/249515/54363) to your earlier and almost identical question is quite clear?

If you look at the quotes there, the **obsolete** construction that you are asking about worked like this:

> Do not eat fish unless than it is fresh.

Which in *non-obsolete* English would be rendered as

> Do not eat fish unless it is fresh.

The "lesser condition" that seems to confuse you is quite simply:

> Do not eat fish if it is less than fresh.

The condition of it not being fresh is a *lesser condition* than the mentioned condition of the fish being fresh.

To make it even clearer, consider:

> Do not sell the house unless than an offer of 200k is on the table.

The condition is *an offer of 200k is on the table*. In the case of any lesser condition (less than 200k being offered), *do not sell the house*.

Comment: Couldn't you as requested clarify that offerings of more than 200k would actually be acceptable by saying, "Do not sell the house unless an offer of *at least* 200k is on the table"? The problem with the word 'fresh' is that it's Boolean in nature: you are either fresh or you are not. There is no direction to be more or less fresh. It isn't a quantity. You could instead say, "Do not eat fish older than 3 days", or "Do not invest in companies unless the are at least 2 years old" because both of those, like the house price, are actually quantities.

Comment: "Fresh" is not Boolean. Your nose can tell the difference between fish that is "less than fresh" and fish that is old. It is a continuum. Perhaps not quantifiable in discrete increments, but that's often the nature of a continuum.

Comment: Thanks. I did cogitate over StoneyB's answer, but I still failed to connect the obsolete definition to a modern use of 'syntax'.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do X in circumstances that do not meet or satisfy condition Y.

Don't {blow up the munitions dump} unless {the invading army has entered the city}.

fall short of ~ in less than